# MySql group by with where condition not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join

I have 2 tables, **groups** and **questions**. I need the result in such a way that it contains group name and corresponding non-deleted question count.
The structure and data for the two tables are as afollows.

[image: groups-table]

[image]

My expected Result is as follows

[image]

I tried the following code, but it gives the entire row including the deleted questions.

```
$groupname = DB::table('groups as d')
        ->select([
            'd.id','d.group_name',DB::raw("count(dtls.survey_group_id) as count")
        ])
        ->leftJoin('questions as dtls','d.id', '=', 'dtls.survey_group_id')
        ->whereNotExists( function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('questions')
            ->where('id', 'd.id')
            ->where('dtls.is_deleted', 1);
        })
        ->groupBy('d.id','d.group_name')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: Since `questions` is participating in the query isn't it the same to say `where('dtls.is_deleted', 1)` instead of the nested query?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help into providing reproducible example data and expected results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem here is that `->where('id', 'd.id')` mathches `id` with the literal string `d.id` which obviously is not what you want. In addition, inner query tables should be aliased to prevent ambiguity. You can try changing it to:

```php
$groupname = DB::table('groups as d')
        ->select([
            'd.id','d.group_name',DB::raw("count(dtls.survey_group_id) as count")
        ])
        ->leftJoin('questions as dtls','d.id', '=', 'dtls.survey_group_id')
        ->whereNotExists( function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('questions as innerDtls')
            ->whereRaw('innerDtls.id = d.id')
            ->where('dtls.is_deleted', 1);
        })
        ->groupBy('d.id','d.group_name')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Alternatively your current query can be simplified to:

```php
$groupname = DB::table('groups as d')
        ->select([
            'd.id','d.group_name',DB::raw("count(dtls.survey_group_id) as count")
        ])
        ->leftJoin('questions as dtls','d.id', '=', 'dtls.survey_group_id')
        ->where('dtls.is_deleted', 0)
        ->groupBy('d.id','d.group_name')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked.. :) and in the 1st case it can also be simplified as ->whereRaw('innerDtls.id= d.id and dtls.is_deleted=1');